# How can I clear the doubt in an interviewers mind that I will leave the job soon?

Tags: interviewing, fresher

About me:
I am a pre-final year student, studying for B.E. in Information Technology.
Currently, I have some projects that show that I have some research interest and frankly (I have). However, for now, I want to work for some years before thinking about Research.

The problem is

> Every time I apply to some company, the interviewer always asks me
>   about my interest in research (due to my projects) and no matter, how
>   much I tell them that I will work for now, there is always a doubt
>   left in their mind that I will leave the job very soon.

So, my question is **How do I clear this doubt in the interviewer's mind?**

Comment: I don't think your current question is very answerable for us, however I think that if you rephrase it to 'How can I clear the doubt in an interviewers mind that I will leave the job soon' we might be able to help you out.

Comment: edited the question as that will help me better

Comment: @Joe Strazzere that is tricky indeed. I have my interests in information security and cryptography and one things leads to another and then we start talking about projects, projects that I would like to do and in some sense they sound like business ideas. This definitely gets me in trouble. In one interview, the interview asked me "if the idea goes off, will you leave the company and pursue it?" and he didn't take no for an answer. It took a lot of time for me to divert his attention from that question.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Why does your interest in research make them think you will leave the company soon? Do you mean that you are interested in pure academic research, so companies in industry are worried you'll leave? Why not apply for jobs in an R&D type environment where you *are* doing research?

Comment: @DavidK The thing is that they think I would go for M.S. and leave the company very soon. Besides, I think it's very difficult for graduates to get an R&D type job without higher education (MS or PhD).

Comment: @scipsycho *Do* you want to get a higher degree? Would you want to leave the company to do so, or would you consider getting an MS while working full time? Most employers offer programs that would cover some education while you work for them.

Comment: @DavidK I think I want to work for sometime before anything. That's why the question. That education program is a good thing you told me about. I will be sure to look them up. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you might be getting into the trap of telling your interviewer what you don't want to do. This is unlikely to achieve much. It might just be the choice of words in your question, but any time you tell an interviewer you want to work "for now", they're going to wonder how long that will last.

If you spin it around and tell the interviewer why you want the job they're advertising, it should be possible to link at least some of the things you've learned in your projects to aspects of that job. The trick is to think of research as preparation for the job and not as an activity that might lead you somewhere else.

Tell them about the curiosity that drives you to look into things, and tell them how you could use that to their benefit.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it would be helpful to try and claim you weren't interested in research so I'd say that while research is something you are interested in and may choose to focus on at some point in your life you are more interested in applying yourself to your working career and the challenges that can provide for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score -2):

For an employer hiring a student is an investment. It is thought in the long run and you try to catch students in order to shape their skills without contamination.

What you can do is answering:

> yes, i love research and dedicate to it all my free time, it's my best hobby. Concerning work, i have to eat pay the rent and live so i'm not leaving anytime soon.

tackle the interviewer as you both know what's his own concern and it's useless to let him imagine his own answer instead of you giving the real one.

Comment: Sorry, the proposed answer will not help. There are many full-time researchers that can eat and pay rent, in fact some of us live rather comfortably from our salary. From this answer the interviewer should infer that OP will leave as soon as they find a payed research position.

Comment: I disagree. One needs some hobby and a recruiter will consider that your hobby by definition can't become your work. Because if so it couldn't be called an hobby at all.

Comment: There are many people who transformed their hobby into a job. In fact, most people dream about making a living from their hobby.

Comment: What are you talking about? You are incredibly wrong mate. From the dictionary:
>an activity done regularly in one's leisure time for pleasure.

Comment: I can't say that I fully agree with this, but this certainly will not leave good impression on interviewer as even though I am talking about my hobby but the interviewer might think that this job is basically a means for me to make money and pursue my true goal i.e. "Research" and so basically my only motivation for this job is "Money". I am not denying that people do job for money but if my sole reason is "money", then I bet he will think that this job is not any special to me and might as well give chance to other candidates.

Comment: do what you want, i have to recruit people for my company and every recruiter i have talked in my entire life consider having hobbies a huge plus when deciding candidates. good luck whatever you chose.... it seems like your actual strategy is not working so i would reconsider something...

Comment: Saying that you want to research as a hobby isn't a bad thing in of itself - suggesting that work will be something done just to eat and pay the rent etc sounds a little dismissive to me. The subtext is very much "I don't want to be here, I just can't earn money from my research so I guess this will do"

Comment: Damn you all live on the clouds. FIRST RULE WHEN YOU INTERVIEW A POTENTIAL EMPLOYEE IS: THE MOMRE HE NEEDS MONEY THE MORE HE WILL STAY THERE AND WORK HARD. When you can't eat or pay the rent you can't live so what are you all talking about..... it's called workspace not far far away

Comment: @pep1 Beyond a certain payment level (in particular for "knowledge workers") you don't want money to be their only motivation. Other perks become much more important and are much better to induce loyalty. Your experiences seem to be from a specific industry (probably mostly low income workers) in a specific society.

Comment: Let me understand you are pointing at edgy (high income jobs) cases as examples to answer to the OP that is a PRE-final year student and also saying that MINE are too specific. Great logic. I am done here :)

Comment: @pep1 There's a big difference between money being *a* motivating factor (unless you're already independently wealthy it will be for everyone) and it being the *only* motivating factor, and when you're discussing a "hobby" that has realistic potential to be a source of income companies are likely to want to see some evidence that you aren't just a short-term stopgap.

Comment: @motosubatsu fair enough, even though i am more than sure that my answer did not pointed that money were the only motivating factor but i just proposed a way to take it easy and let understand the employer that since i am applying for the job i have plans to stay there bc as you said everyone needs money for living.... i think you all should realize that interviewer are used to 'I am super exited to work for this great company!' and 'i will work very hard to hold this position' while honesty is so rare that they are impressed from a so easy and legit response.

Comment: @pep1 I've openly said that "money" was my driving factor in going for a job more than once - as you say some interviewers (myself included) can find that honesty very refreshing. The specific issue I had with your answer was because of the implication being that "money" only works as a reason if the candidate has no other obvious potential source that they would prefer. Since getting into a paying research position is far more feasible than someone whose hobbies include say singing turning that into a paying career what you suggest would be the kind of statement that would have the exact...

Comment: ...opposite effect to what the OP is trying to achieve - worrying the potential employer that the OP would jump ship for a research gig in a flash.

Comment: Indicating that you're only interested in the job for money just tells the interviewer that you will be easily enticed into a new role that offers slightly more money. Unless it's the kind of role which requires no skill and is easily replaced, you never want to give the indication that you would be happy to leave at the drop of a hat - this answer just suggests replacing "research" as the motivation with "money".